# Why is this get request not working as intended with the advanced search?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When I run the request/ push the search button on the advanced search, it gives me all of the animals in my database and not the ones specified on the advanced search. As seen in backend, no console.log is working.

How can I change my code to make is so that when one or more of the filters is applied it displays the proper animals

Front end:

```
const getAdvancedPets = async (type, adoptionStatus, height, weight, name) =>{
        try{
            const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/all-pets?type=${type}&status=${adoptionStatus}&height=${height}&weight=${weight}&name=${name}`)
            // http://localhost:8080/api/all-pets/${type}/${adoptionStatus}/${height}/${weight}/${name}
            console.log(res)
            return res.data
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    const animalTypeChange= (value) => {
        setAnimalType(value)
    }
    const adoptionStatusChange= (e) => {
        setAdoptionStatus(e.target.value)
    }
    const heightChange= (e) => {
        setHeight(e.target.value)
    }
    const weightChange= (e) => {
        setWeight(e.target.value)
    }
    const nameChange= (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleAdvancedSearch = async () => {
        const type = animalType;
        const status = adoptionStatus;
        const petHeight = height;
        const petWeight = weight;
        const petName = name;
        const pets = await getAdvancedPets(type, status, petHeight, petWeight, petName);
        setPets(pets);
    }
```

Backend:

```
petsRouter.get('/', async (request, response) => {
    // console.log(request.query); not loggin anything
    const { type, status, height, weight, name } = request.query;
    let typeQuery;
    if (type === 'other') {
      typeQuery = { $not: { $in: ['cat', 'dog'] } };
    } else {
      typeQuery = type;
    }
  
    const pets = await Pet.find({ type: typeQuery, status, height, weight, name });
    response.status(200).json(pets);
});
```